# Reverse words of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to reverse the words of a string in Ruby, without using the reverse method. I want to implement the known algorithm of:

- Reverse the whole string
- Reverse each word in the reversed string.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
class String
  def custom_reverse(start, limit)
    i_start = start
    i_end = limit - 1

    while (i_start <= i_end)
      tmp = self[i_start]
      self[i_start] = self[i_end]
      self[i_end] = tmp
      i_start += 1
      i_end -= 1
    end
    return self
  end

  def custom_reverse_words
    self.custom_reverse(0, self.size)

    i_start = 0
    i_end = 0

    while (i_end <= self.length)
      if (i_end == self.length || self[i_end] == ' ')
        self.custom_reverse(i_start, i_end)
        i_start += 1
      end

      i_end += 1
    end
  end
end

test_str = "hello there how are you"
p test_str.custom_reverse_words
```

But the results are "`yahthello ow ou er ereh`"

What am I missing?

Comment: An academic exercise? Just curious what your constraints are.

Comment: Not academic. I am just trying to practice Ruby from interview questions, without using some of its high-level methods.

Comment: You are referencing characters you have already changed! Try storing the entire string in a temporary variable and using that for the reference

Comment: So that is an academic question, you're trying to learn, since in production code you'd just use `reverse`.

Comment: I wonder why the -1. Isn't his a proper question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of any reverse operation is to iterate over elements in the reverse order of what you'd normally do. That is, where you'd usually use the set (0..N-1) you'd instead go through (N-1..0) or more specifically N-1-i where i is 0..N-1:

```
class String
  def reverse_words
    split(/\s+/).map{|w|wl=w.length-1;(0..wl).map{|i|w[wl-i]}.join}.join(' ')
  end
end

puts "this is reverse test".reverse_words.inspect
# => "siht si esrever tset"
```

The same principle can be applied to the words in a given string.

Interview questions of this sort are of highly dubious value. Being "clever" in production code is usually a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: +1 for "Interview questions of this sort are of highly dubious value.".

Comment: tadman, I completely agree with you, but if you are in an interview, and you are asked to reverse the words of a string, and you go ahead and do ``my_str.split(' ').reverse.join(' ')``, most likely the interviewer wants to know if you understand an algorithm to do so, and avoid using high level functions. Right?

Comment: @HommerSmith To properly prepare for the worst kind of technical interview you'd need to have canned solutions for pretty much every logic puzzle ever invented, be able to code in assembly for every chip ever made, and know *Introduction to Algorithms* and the gang-of-four *Design Patterns* books inside and out. While this makes you a better candidate, I'm not sure it makes you a better programmer, nor that you'd want to work for a company that places such high value in these things.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to reverse an array without using the built-in `reverse`:

```
class Array
  def reverse 
    tmp_ary = self.dup
    ret_ary = []
    self.size.times do
      ret_ary << tmp_ary.pop
    end
    ret_ary
  end
end

%w[a b c].reverse # => ["c", "b", "a"]
```

`tmp_ary.pop` is the secret. `pop` removes elements from the end of the array.

Comment: All quality answers to this one! +1

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution I could think of is:

```
class Array
  def my_reverse
    sort_by.with_index {|_, i| -i}
  end
end

class String
  def words
    split(/\W+/)
  end

  def revert_words
    words.my_reverse.join(' ')
  end

  def revert_each_word
    words.map {|w| w.chars.my_reverse.join}.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice and clean, Broi, though I do like @Kevin's suggestion of having a method `reverse_chars` (or maybe `reverse_word`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
class String
  def reverse_words
    split.inject([]){|str, word| str.unshift word}.join(' ')
  end

  def reverse_chars
    each_char.inject([]){|str, char| str.unshift char}.join('')
  end
end
```

## Revised

Carey raises a good point, reverse_chars can be simplified, since string is already an Enumerable:

```
class String
  def reverse_chars
    each_char.inject(""){|str, char| str.insert(0, char) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one, Kevin. +1 I like the fact that for `reverse_chars` you do not convert to an array and back. Note you don't need `join('')`--it's already a string.

Comment: Thanks Cary. I think if you prepopulate inject with an array, you still need the join, but you raise a good point. I'm editing my answer with a simpler approach.

Comment: Ha! I was mixing strings and arrays in my brain when I made my first comment, which was incorrect, so no attribution, please. I hadn't read your method carefully.  When I saw `str unshift char` I thought `unshift` to be a string method (probably because I've wished for that in the past), in which case the object must have been an empty string, which it was not.

Answer (score 1):

Once you define a simple and efficient array reverser:

```
def reverse_array(a)
  (a.length / 2).times {|i| a[i],a[-(i+1)] = a[-(i+1)],a[i]}
  a
end
```

You can reverse a sentence pretty straightforwardly:

```
def reverse_sentence(s)
  reverse_array(s.split('')).join.split(" ").map{|w| reverse_array(w.split('')).join}.join(" ")
end

reverse_sentence "Howdy pardner"     # => "pardner Howdy"
```

Comment: Nice one with the parallel assignment!